# How to remove shadow below UINavigationBar with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Image 1]

I could successfully remove the shadow below the navigation bar with the following line of code.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

[image: Image 2]

When I added a search controller however, the shadow reappeared.

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

[image: Image 3]

I tried the following, but resulted an unexpected behavior.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

[image: Image 4]

How do I remove the shadow under a navigation bar when there is a search controller attached?

Comment: try with `self.navigationItem.searchController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Lots of people are having this problem https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86828

Answer (score 6):

I have not found good solution too...

for now I will hide it this way:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let imageView = navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.superview?.subviews.first?.subviews.first as? UIImageView {
            imageView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I love Apple for this kind of stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that I use

1. Create a separate class extending a `UINavigationController` instance, lets call it `BaseNavigationController`. Here's your class for you
2. If you are using storyboards, assign `BaseNavigationController` to your UINavigationController scene in the storyboard
3. If you are initializing a navigation controller via code, ex: `UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: someViewControllerInstance)` then simply use `BaseNavigationController.init(rootViewController: someViewControllerInstance)`

An example of the class is shown below:

```
open class BaseNavigationController:UINavigationController {

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setNavigationBar()
        setNavBarBorder(false)
    }

    func setNavigationBar(color:UIColor?=UIColor.white, tint:UIColor?=UIColor.darkGray){
        let appearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        appearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset.init(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = color!
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = tint!
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: tint! ]
    }

    func setTitleColor(_ color:UIColor?=UIColor.darkGray){

    }

    func setNavBarBorder(_ enable:Bool) {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage((enable ? nil : UIImage()), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = (enable ? nil : UIImage())
        self.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    }

}
```

Now, the fun part, if you are handling ambiguous layout you might need to do this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` otherwise putting this bit of code in `viewWillAppear`
of the viewController instance.

`(self.navigationController as? BaseNavigationController)?. setNavBarBorder(false)`

the interesting bit of code is in `self.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")`, for some versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead add `searchBar` to your viewController in storyBoard and set its ***Search Style*** property to `Minimal` and it'll be look like this:

[image]

Comment: You lose a lot of stuff from UISearchController with this approach sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

My little contribution about this issue. Of course, it is not the right way to do it but it's working for opaque navigation bar. The idea is to add a view on top of this shadow.

```
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
let maskView = UIView(frame: .zero)
maskView.backgroundColor = .white // or any color you want
searchBar.addSubview(maskView)

//We need to use constraint so the mask view follow the search bar animation
maskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let views = ["maskView": maskView]
searchBar.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(0)-[maskView]-(0)-|",
                                                        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterY,
                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                        views: views))
searchBar.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[maskView(1)]-(-1)-|",
                                                        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterX,
                                                        metrics: nil,
                                                        views: views))
```